# Проблема с кодировкой в python при записи в файл от response

Tags: python, unicode

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с неприятной проблемой кодировки в python давно. Но обычно проблема решалась открытием файла в нужной кодировке через модули io или codecs. Однако, в этот раз так не получается.
Дело в том, что я пытаюсь скачать файл в ascii с ссылки http://www.mkrf.ru/opendata/7705851331-immovable_monuments/data-1-structure-1.csv
И он очень большой, поэтому я пишу его так:

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with codecs.open(path, 'wb','utf-8') as handle:
    for block in response.iter_content(1024, decode_unicode=True):
        handle.write(block.decode('utf8'))#здесь он бросает мне UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Пробовал писать через StremWriter - безрезультатно..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы скачать удалённый файл как есть по `http` c помощью [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/), нужно открыть выходной файл в бинарном режиме (`wb`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from contextlib import closing
import requests

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()  # raise on http error (avoid overwriting output)
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
            file.write(chunk)
```

Если также необходимо поддерживать `ftp`, то [можно `urlretrieve()` из стандартной библиотеки использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

url = '...data-1-structure-1.csv'
urlretrieve(url, 'output.csv')
```

Чтобы автоматически имя файла из ссылки изъять, [можно `url2filename()` функцию использовать.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16501351/4279)

Если хочется перекодировать файл в другую кодировку на лету, не сохраняя предварительно в файл, то в общем случае не следует использовать `codecs` или `decode_unicode=True`, который `codecs` внутри использует, если необходимо поддерживать кодировки несовместимые с `ascii` такие как `utf-16`, `utf-32` или если необходимо поддерживать [универсальный режим новых строк](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) (для cvs файла это не важно, но в общем случае это может иметь значение для текстовых файлов).

Например, `block.decode('cp1251')` работает только потому что `cp1251` является однобайтовой кодировкой, в противном случае `.decode()`сломается если ему дать частичный символ -- нет гарантии, что `block` никогда не заканчивается посреди Юникодного символа, представленного в виде нескольких байт, в общем случае.

Вместо этого можно использовать [`io.TextIOWrapper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
from shutil import copyfileobj
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen(url) as r, \
     io.TextIOWrapper(r, encoding=r.headers.get_content_charset('unknown'),
                      newline='') as input_file, \
     open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as output_file:
    copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

---

О коде в вопросе: не следует `decode_unicode=True` и `.decode()` использовать вместе: если `decode_unicode` успешно работает, то `block` уже возвращается как Юникодный текст и поэтому код в вопросе приводит к `AttributeError` на Питоне 3, где Юникодные строки не имеют `.decode()` метод или к `UnicodeEncodeError` (не `UnicodeDecodeError`!!!) при попытке неявно закодировать unicode обратно в bytes на Питоне 2.

Answer (score 0):

Файл и не получится декодировать так, потому что он не `ascii` и не `utf-8`, а вполне себе Windows-1251.

```
handle.write(block.decode('cp1251'))
```

Как следствие, извращения с `codecs` и `decode_unicode` тут, наверно, лишние, я бы написал так:

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as handle:
    for block in response.iter_content(1024):
        handle.write(block.decode('cp1251'))
```

Comment: `block.decode()` здесь нельзя использовать, если содержимое использует многобайтную кодировку (utf-8, utf-16, etc).

Comment: @jfs там Windows-1251, написал же в ответе.

Comment: Это комментарий для людей, у которых файл может быть в другой кодеровке. Поэтому комментарий слово "если" имеет.